# How to retrieve parameter after handling form in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner wih Spring MVC and I want to recuperate a parameter using the controller and use it in another method:

```
@GetMapping("handleForm")
public String  showForm(Model m, @RequestParam int id) {  

    return "showForm";


}

@PostMapping("handleForm")
public String  processFormData(Model m) {  
/* here I want to access the  "id" parameter from the above function, how do I do that? */
}
```

Comment: Usually people do that by adding a hidden form field to their page that contains the ID. No clue if that solves your problem though.

Comment: it doesnt as there seem to be a problem with thymeleaf when it comes to hidden fields:   `<input type="hidden" id="custId" th:value="${id}" th:field="*{idField}"  /> ` returns a null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
     @GetMapping("handleForm")
  public String  showForm(Model m, @RequestParam int id)
  {  
   return "showForm";
  }
   @PostMapping("handleForm/{id}")
   public String  processFormData(@RequestParam("id") String id,Model m) 
  {  
   System.out.println(id);
   }
```

you also have to make the mapping url according to the parameter.

Comment: tried it, it doesn't work , it returns the following error: `Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported`

Comment: can you show me your full code. What do you want to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple just declare one global as `int id` call the `id` where you want to use id value.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at you're code your trying to POST with a request  Param as far as I'm aware you can't do that. You can change to a GET request and send the Param from the form that way or modify the POST request to use a @ModelAttribute.

```
 @GetMapping("handleForm")
  public String  showForm(Model m, @RequestParam int 
 id)
 {  
  return "showForm";
 }
@PostMapping("handleForm")
 public String  processFormData(@ModelAttribute  
  ModelThatContainsId id,Model m) 
 {  
   System.out.println(ModelThatContainsId.getId());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the parameters in url and can simply use @RequestParam to retrieve the parameters from the url.

```
String id;
@GetMapping("/handleForm")
public String  showForm(Model m, @RequestParam int id) {  
this.id = id;
return "showForm";
}

@PostMapping("/handleForm")
public String  processFormData(@RequestParam("id") String id, 
Model M ) {  
String previousId = this.id;
/* here I want to access the  "id" parameter from the above function, how do I 
do that? */
}
```